# Jupyter Notebook Kernel dying: error message, "The process cannot access the file because is being used by another process"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am receiving the below error when I attempt to start up a jupyter notebook file. Jupyter was working fine until my work's administrator gave me admin rights for a few hours. Now the kernel keeps dying and this is what I get.....any help would be greatly appreciated....

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
"C:\Users\dohertym>jupyter notebook
[I 10:41:21.197 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\do
hertym
[I 10:41:21.197 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:41:21.197 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhos
t:8888/
[I 10:41:21.197 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all
 kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 10:41:33.599 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 10:41:35.444 NotebookApp] Kernel started: b7cb839a-a31c-44f3-ba5a-821baf74ca4
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.init_history()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1586, in init_history
    self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 512, in __init__
    **traits)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_db()
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in init_db
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 96, in catch_corrupt_db
    os.rename(self.hist_file, newpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
[I 10:41:38.450 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.init_history()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1586, in init_history
    self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 512, in __init__
    **traits)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_db()
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in init_db
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 96, in catch_corrupt_db
    os.rename(self.hist_file, newpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
[I 10:41:41.467 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.init_history()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1586, in init_history
    self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 512, in __init__
    **traits)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_db()
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in init_db
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 96, in catch_corrupt_db
    os.rename(self.hist_file, newpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
[I 10:41:44.473 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.init_history()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1586, in init_history
    self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 512, in __init__
    **traits)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_db()
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in init_db
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 96, in catch_corrupt_db
    os.rename(self.hist_file, newpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
[W 10:41:45.848 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from b7cb839a
-a31c-44f3-ba5a-821baf74ca41
[I 10:41:47.483 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel b7cb839a-a31c-44f3-ba5a-821baf74ca41 restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line
72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ip
ykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tr
aitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 465, in __init__
    self.init_history()
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1586, in init_history
    self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 512, in __init__
    **traits)
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_db()
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in init_db
  File "C:\Users\dohertym\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IP
ython\core\history.py", line 96, in catch_corrupt_db
    os.rename(self.hist_file, newpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process
[W 10:41:50.496 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 10:41:50.496 NotebookApp] Kernel b7cb839a-a31c-44f3-ba5a-821baf74ca41 died, r
emoving from map.
ERROR:root:kernel b7cb839a-a31c-44f3-ba5a-821baf74ca41 restarted failed!
[W 10:41:50.553 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 10:41:50.555 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/b4459498-6cd5-41dc-8f37-89
fdaca7dce4 (127.0.0.1) 3.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled78
.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[I 10:43:35.355 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled78.ipynb"
```

Comment: From looking at the stack trace, it seems that Jupyter is attempting to load move a corrupt history file, which is a SQLite3 DB. Do you currently have another jupyter session that is using the sqlite file?

Comment: I have closed out all sessions and ended all processes related. Not sure where the DB could be that it is attempting to open.....